# how to copy specific columns from CSV file to postgres table using psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am trying to read a data from csv file to postgres table. I have two columns in  table, but there are four fields in csv data file. I want to read only two specific columns from csv to table.

Answer (score 0):

Would you know how to do it if there were only those two columns in CSV file?

If yes, then the simplest solution is to transform the CSV prior to importing into Postgres.

Comment: i know how to so it if the no of columns are same in table and csv. BUt i wanted to know if there is any other faster method.

Comment: Then probably the easiest way to proceed is for you to post the code you would use in that case, and someone will probably easily edit it to provide the customization you want. It's much easier than inventing such code from scratch, at least to me.